# Probability exercise (exponential variable)

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, density-function

Can you help me to solve this exercise? I do not understand how to solve some points and my exam is coming soon. I have solved some items but I am in doubt about them

It asks:

> A cell phone manufacturer offers warranty for $9$ months with a free replacement if the device was defective. The manufacturer estimates that each of the unit has an average life that corresponds to and exponential variable with mean equal to $24$ months
>
> a) What probability of defective devicees will be replaced?
>
> b) What is the density function for duration of devices that won't have any failure before $8$ months
>
> c) Derek is a VIP member, he has infinite warranty. He can replace his phone every time is fails. If his first cellphone lasts more than a year, what is that probabilkity that $3$ phones won't cover $5$ year?

a)(NOT SURE)

$f(x) = \frac 1{24} e^{-x/24}$ , $x > 0$

---

$P( x \leq 9) = \frac 1{24} \int_0^9 e^{-x/24}\text dx$

$u= \frac x{24}$

$\text du = \frac{\text dx}{24} $

\begin{align}\frac 1{24} \int e^{-x/24} \text dx &= \int e^{-u} \text du \\
\\&= -e^{-u} 
\\&= -e^{-x/24} \end{align}

---

\begin{align}F(x) &= -e^{-x/24}\\
F(9) &= -e^{-9/24}\\
F(0) &= - e^0 \\
&= -1 \\
&\Downarrow\\
F(9)-F(0) &= 1- e^{-9/24} \\
&= 0.3127 \end{align}

---

b)(NOT SURE)

$$P( x < 8) = \frac 1{24} \int_0^8  e^{-x/24}\text dx = 0.2835$$

Poisson with parameter $\lambda = 0.2835$ (The distribution of duration devices with failute time $< 8$ months)

---

c)I have no idea

Comment: (c) can be solved by combining memorylessness and the Poisson distribution

Comment: @Henry thank you for replying.. What about points a) and b)?

Comment: @Henry, if you have a little time off.. can check this exercise?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357606/probability-exercise-random-variable/2357732#2357732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Seems right.
2. You have to find the conditional density $f_{X|X>8}(x)$, thus by definition
   $$
   f_{X|X>8}(x) = \frac{f_X(x)I\{X>8\}}{P(X>8)} = \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}I\{X>8\}}{e^{-\lambda 8}} = \lambda e^{-\lambda(x-8)}, \quad x\ge8.
   $$
   Namely, it is a shifted exponential distribution.
3. Using the memoreyless property, we have $4$ years and maximum $3$ phones, namely you are asking what is the probability that a life duration of $3$ i.i.d phones will be less then $4$, i.e., 
   $$
   Y_3 = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 \sim \mathcal{G}(\lambda, 3), 
   $$
   hence
   $$
   P(Y_3 \le 4) = \int_{0}^4 \frac{ \lambda ^3 }{2!}e^{-\lambda y}y^2dy = P(N(4)>3) =  1- \sum _{n=0}^3 \frac{e^{-4\lambda}(4\lambda)^n}{n!}.
   $$
   Where $N(4) \sim Poiss (4 \lambda)$.

Comment: Thank you for replyting mate!
Can i ask you something?.Why 4 years?5 years?

Comment: @JustToKnow "his first cellphone lasts more than a year" and the exponential distribution is memoryless

Comment: $4$ years because it is already known that the first phone survived the first year, thus, due to memoryless property, it has the same conditional distribution as the original, i.e., we start over again with the same probabilities and parameters at $t=1$.

Comment: V.V : $X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ does not have an exponential distribution but a Gamma distribution.  Or you can turn this into a Poisson distribution question

Comment: Ohh i get it now, I feel really dumb :/..
Thank you very much @V.V

Comment: Thank you @Henry. I've confused it carelessly with $\min\{X_1,..,X_3\}$. Now corrected.

Comment: @JustToKnow you are welcome! And you can click on "accept" if it answers  your question.

Comment: @V.V can you take a look at this?:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357606/probability-exercise-random-variable/2357732#2357732